# Changing "na" values in "NaN" or "0"

Tags: python, pandas

Is that ok to change "na" values to "NaN" in panda data frame.or "0" is the best..
I changed the "na" values to "NaN".but in the outcome all the integers changed into float.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.